# Changing max message size of for rabbitmq

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq

i am currently using rabbitmq version 3.7 on my project.
I'm generating my rabbitmq image on a docker-compose.

My question is how do i change from the default message size of 512mb to ~2gb.

```
  rabbit:
    container_name: rabbitMQ
    hostname: rabbit
    image: "rabbitmq:3.7-management"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      # - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
```

From what i gathered i needed to change a property on rabbitmq.conf, but everything i tried didn't have an effect on the allowed size in production.
Is it even possible to change this value?

Comment: Yes, the rabbitmq.conf file is where you would set this.  The property is max_message_size.  In our company, we use classic config, which would look like this:
`[
  {rabbit, [
    {max_message_size, 2000000000}
  }]
].`

Comment: Thank you Chad, follow up question: Just copy and paste '[   {rabbit, [     {max_message_size, 2000000000}   }] ]' into rabbitmq.conf?
or only '{max_message_size, 2000000000}'?

Comment: If you are using the classic config style, then paste that whole object.